# Google Analytics: What is the limit of tracked pageviews per month?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, google-ads, page

I have been looking around to try and find some confirmation and clarity on the limit of pageviews that Google allow per month for a Google Analytics account.

I have read that the limit of **hits** per month is 10,000,000, and the limit of pageviews is 5,000,000. Putting 2 and 2 together I am thinking this is to allow the other 5,000,000 for events and social clicks and the like?

[Google's documentation](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1008065#cost) states 5 million, but the hits/pageviews is a bit of a grey area as I've read suggestions that the limit can be considered as 10 million.

Comment: It would appear as though you've found the answer in the documentation - what is left to be answered?

Comment: Related: [Site too large to officially use Google Analytics?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/site-too-large-to-officially-use-google-analytics)

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 5 000 000 pageviews per month as registered by Google Analytics (just open your report to see how many you have). It **cannot** be considered as 10m. No idea where you read that, but don't believe everything that's posted on the Internet ;)

Per Google:

> This free version is limited to 5 million pageviews a month - however, users with an active Google AdWords account are given unlimited pageview tracking. In addition, Google Analytics is completely integrated into the AdWords front-end and with your AdWords campaign, making it easy to track your AdWords ROI.

So, there are two ways of avoiding this limit:

1. Paying for Google Analytics pro service (expensive)
2. Paying for AdWords campagin (even if you run small and cheap campagin - you are still free to use it)

Choice is yours :)

Other thing is that google tends to be very forgiving about that - I have a website that each year for a single month exceeded 5m pageviews and yet Google never complained nor asked for anything, so... happy me! ;)