# Is Google analytics free of charge?

Tags: google-analytics

I was reading the Google Analytics' Terms of Service http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/tos.html , and I am curious about the 2º Section of it.

It states: 
2. FEES AND SERVICES . Subject to Section 15 herein, the Service is provided without charge to You for up to 5 million pageviews per month per account, and if You have an active Adwords campaign in good standing, the Service is provided without charge to You without a pageview limitation.

I think we have some misled information about the "Freeness" of Google Analytics. Most people choose this tool for this reason...

Some people may think that Adwords is not a good choice of media for their products, so they may not use it. Others, might not advertise online at all! 
If their website has lots of traffic, Google Analytics is not a (free) choice!

The Term states that "if You have an active Adwords campaign in good standing, the Service is provided without charge to You without a pageview limitation." 
What limits an adwords account from not-active to an active or a bad standing to a good standing. A good standing means a monthly investment in adwords of $100? $1000? $10000?

How much does Google charge for non-adwords Google Analytics users whom have more than 5mi PVs per month? Is it charged by each extra PV or a fixed monthly charge?

Comment: Google Analytics is free. There are sites that have a ton of traffic and may opt for paying for a better level of service. At some point, traffic statistics is aggregated otherwise. I do not use Adwords since I have nothing to sell and my site is somewhat lousy and not worth advertising. And yet, I use GA. I do also use Adsense which may help. What the level of Adwords commitment is, I cannot say. I will leave that up to someone else to answer.

Answer (score 5):

> the Service is provided without charge to You for up to 5 million pageviews per month per account

As long as you do not exceed 5 million impressions per month, Google Analytics is free. This is generally not an issue for most small business and personal users.

> if You have an active Adwords campaign in good standing, the Service is provided without charge to You without a pageview limitation

The monthly impression cap is lifted if you have a current AdWords campaign, and your AdWords account is not [suspended or disabled](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375414?hl=en).

If your site does get more than 5 million impressions per month and you do not use AdWords, or you need advanced features or professional support, a [premium version](http://www.google.com/analytics/premium/) is available for $150,000 a year. Google Analytics Premium can handle up to one billion impressions per month.

See also: [Site too large to officially use Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/site-too-large-to-officially-use-google-analytics) and [Google Analytics: What is the limit of tracked pageviews per month?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38494/google-analytics-what-is-the-limit-of-tracked-pageviews-per-month)